# Detecting existing string in file in bash

Tags: bash, concatenation

I'm creating a `bash` installer script for a project. In it, i need to modify the file descriptor count. I do this by modifying the files `/etc/security/limits.conf`, `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, and `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`.

Here is the code in the `bash installer script`

```
echo "
*    soft nofile 64000
*    hard nofile 64000
root soft nofile 64000
root hard nofile 64000
" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "session required pam_limits.so" >> /etc/pam.d/common-session
echo "session required pam_limits.so" >> /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
```

The issue is, if for some reason the project installation fails and it passes this check point, rerunning it will subsequently **add this string into the files again.**

Is there a way I can detect if the strings are already existent in each of the files and if so not execute the addition.

I'm an intermediate bash user but this is beyond my skill set and I don't believe I can do this on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this utility function that searches a given file and appends only when string is not found in file:

```
searchAppend() { grep -qF "$2" "$1" || echo "${3:-$2}" >> "$1"; }
```

and use it as:

```
str="
*    soft nofile 64000
*    hard nofile 64000
root soft nofile 64000
root hard nofile 64000
"
searchAppend /etc/security/limits.conf 'root soft nofile 64000' "$str"
searchAppend /etc/pam.d/common-session 'session required pam_limits.so'
searchAppend /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive 'session required pam_limits.so'
```

As per `man bash`:

> `${parameter:-word}`
>                 Use **Default Values**.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

[Shell Parameter Expansion
Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: the limits.conf you wrote is much smaller

Comment: but now im only inserting the one line instead of all lines

Comment: With some grep versions you can use `-Z` to search for multi-line strings. Simply write `-qFZ` instead of `-qF` and you should be able to use the strings from your example.

Comment: can you explain the echo portion of the search append function so i understand

Comment: Function has an optional 3rd parameter which is string to be appended. If 3rd argument is not provided then 2nd search string will be appended. `"${3:-$2}"` checks if `$3` is empty then use `$2`

Comment: k i understand but what does the : and - mean

Comment: c.f. [this reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for a good overview of built-in bash string processing tools. ;)

Comment: Thanks @PaulHodges, adding this link in my answer.

Comment: everything works great but for the limits.conf file its only adding root soft nofile 64000 not the entire string

Comment: Are you passing 3rd argument `"$str"` as I have shown in my answer? Also make sure you're using `bash`

Comment: nvm i see the function was updated sorry i didnt update in my code